# SELECT from two tables in mysql and display all the row's in the column in one of them?

Tags: php, mysql

okay, I'm a bit baffled with this one and I'm not entirely sure how to even explain it. I will try my best to explain it and i hope you guys understand what i mean!

I have a table in mysql called `members` which stores the members data.
I also have a table which is called `transactions` which stores the orders/transactions made by the users.

what i need to do is this:

**1-** select both of the tables.

**2-** look to see which columns in both tables have the same email address (the emails are saved in both tables).

**3-** finally display the result from the `transactions` table with the same `email`.

I've tried something like this but i know this is wrong:

```
<?php 
// Query member data from the database and ready it for display
$sql = "SELECT payer_email FROM transactions
UNION
SELECT email FROM members";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($count > 1) {
    echo "There is no user with that id here.";
    exit(); 
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
$email2 = $sql;
}
?>
```

could someone please help me out with this?

EDIT:

[image]

EDIT:

HERE IS WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:
Please ignore the mysql queries, i will convert them to mysqli before going live. this is just for a test.

```
<?php 
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$dynamicList22 = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT 
t.payer_email,
t.first_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT( t.payer_email )
FROM
transactions t
INNER JOIN
members m
ON( m.email = t.payer_email )
GROUP BY t.payer_email");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
             $payer_email = $row["payer_email"];
             $dynamicList22 .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="17%" valign="top">'. $payer_email .'</td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: If I understand properly you want to look at doing a SQL `join` on the email field

Comment: @geedubb, sort of yes. i want to search for the same email(s) in both table and then display the result from the `transactions` table. so if an email is `myemai@yahoo.co.uk` in both tables. i want to display the `item_name` which is stored in the `transactions` table for that email.

Answer (score 2):

Use Inner join as

```
select * from `transactions` inner join `members` on `members`.`email` = `transactions`.`email`
```

Comment: For more information on `inner joins`: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: okay, Thanks but how do i show the result from one of the tables (the `transactions` table). basically i want to display `item_name` in the `transactions` table if the email addresses match!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT 
t.payer_email,
t.first_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT( t.item_name ) AS item_name
FROM
transactions t
INNER JOIN
members m
ON( m.email = t.payer_email )
GROUP BY t.payer_email
```

[Read more about GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) ..

Comment: okay, Thanks but how do i show the result from one of the tables (the `transactions` table). basically i want to display `item_name` in the `transactions` table if the email addresses match!

Comment: You can add any field that you wish to.. Or select all fields like `t.*`. I have updated the answer..

Comment: i think you misunderstood me! sorry for explaining it badly. I want to search in both tables for similar emails and IF there are two emails that match in both tables then display the `item_name` column which is only in the `transactions` table.

Comment: Do you need all the rows from the `transactions` table?

Comment: It would be better if you can explain with an example!

Comment: no, not all of them. just a couple of them! one of them is `item_name` and the other one is the `first_name`.

Comment: I wanted to know, that do u want all ROWS? Edit the question with a sample input and a sample output..

Comment: someone downvoted me for some reason and i cannot post a picture! could you please upvote me so i can edit my question with an image that explains everything better?

Comment: I have edited the answer... In future make sure that you are giving all the required information in the question. :) Happy to help!

Comment: Unfortunately that only gets the first item_name in the mysql table!

Comment: Did you add `GROUP BY t.payer_email` as well, in the end of the query? If yes, then how many rows are you getting in the final output??

Comment: Yes, I did add the `GROUP BY t.payer_email` at the end of the query too. at the moment i get 2 rows in the output! one for `user1` and the other one for `user2`. no matter if I'm logged in as `user1` or `user2`. I see orders for `user1` in `user2` account and i see orders for `user2` in `user1` account!

Comment: I have also, edited my question with my current code. I've changed the `item_name` to `payer_email` in my code to see what happens and still get two emails for user1 and user2 in the output.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT( t.payer_email )` is absolutely wrong.. :P :P See my answer again.!